# The most efficient way to show the local image in android

Tags: android, image, performance, bitmap, inputstream

I am currently work on a magazine like apps. Since there is an option to zoom in(150%, 200%, 250% of original source) , I would prefer not to scale down the image. However , the app will force restart when I try to decode the image because of the out of memory. Are there any suggestion to fix that?

The image are local (SD card) , can be retrieve in any approach, but eventually need to be a bitmap as I use something like cavans.drawbitmap to display it. I tried, input stream-> bytes , input stream->bitmap etc... but are there any most efficient way or at least 
I can sure the app does not force restart / close?  Thanks

```
 try {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
            try {
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            } finally {
                is.close();                    
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), defaultDrawable);


   }
```

Comment: Welcome to suggest the native solution for the memory problem

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using [nostra's image loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), it deals with memory quite efficiently, you can specify lots of config stuffs, im using it and its working pretty well for large images aswell

Comment: Thanks for helping, sorry but considering no lib is using in the project ,are there any native way ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is what smartImageView(by loopj - you can find him on http://loopj.com/) uses to retrieve files from the drive/sd.

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromDisk(String imgID) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    if(diskCacheEnabled){
        String filePath = getFilePath(imgID);
        File file = new File(filePath);
        if(file.exists()) {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
        }
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, sorry but considering no lib is using in the project ,are there any native way ? Doesnt mind if it is slightly less efficency, Thanks

Comment: You can go to loopj's gitHub(his code is open source) and check out the way he/she has coded it. I learned from his code, made some changes to meet my needs and it's pretty straight forward. I've never had problems with it. You don't have to use his lib, just learn from what he is doing :)